# How to create "Upcoming dates" app for artists to display gig date in description section

Tags: soundcloud

I'd like to know if it's possible to create my own app that can display upcoming gigs (dates) of an artist inside description section on Soundcloud profile.

I know that SongKick and GigaTools offer this option, but I'm not sure if this is because of a special partnership or it's possible to do it via Soundcloud API.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

You can point me to the right resources in the API documentation and I'll take it from there, I just couldn't find it.

Thank you!